# Connections in non-commutative geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-geometry, connections

Let $K$ be a field, $A$ a unital associative $K$-algebra and $M$ a left $A$-module. A connection on $M$ is a $K$-linear map $\nabla:M\to \Omega^1A\otimes_AM$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule. According to Lemma 18.4.4 of Ginzburg's Lectures on Noncommutative Geometry ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506603v1)), $M$ admits a connection iff $M$ is projective.

How can we generalize this to general modules?

Taking a projective resolution $P_\bullet\to M$ and defining a connection as a chain map $\nabla:P_\bullet\to\Omega^1A\otimes_AP_\bullet$ seemed plausible, but once we take its homology, $\nabla$ descends to a connection on $M$, which I don't want.

Any comments or references are appreciated.

Comment: If neither (1) considering the analog of a superconnection [section 1.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0249.pdf ] or (2) considering sheaves of complexes of modules [ https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374215 ] 

are helpful then I probably have nothing more to add!